# Null Point Exception -> editText.getText().toString()

Tags: java, android

I'm getting Null Point Exception when I do this:

```
 String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
```

Here's the code:

```
public static class PointCreation extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.point_creation, container, false);

        Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
        buttonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tou a carregar no botao guardar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                final EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
                final EditText ObservationField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Observation);
                String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
                String Observation = ObservationField.getText().toString();
                pointsList.add(new Point("Serial", Observation, false, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                        5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Observation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        Button buttonApagar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tou a carregar no botao apagar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here's the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serial"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Serial"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Serial"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/serial"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Observations"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/serial"
        android:text="Observações" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Observation"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Observations"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/serial"
        >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
04-09 17:07:38.639  14736-14736/com.example.testlayout.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testlayout.app, PID: 14736
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.testlayout.app.PointsList$PointCreation$1.onClick(PointsList.java:120)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the Logcat errors please

Comment: Is the xml posted  `point_creation.xml`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this out of button `onClick`

```
 EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
```

What happens is its looking for `EditText` as a child of `Button` which is not the case

So it should be

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.point_creation, container, false);
        final EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
        final EditText ObservationField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Observation);
        Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
        buttonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tou a carregar no botao guardar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
                String Observation = ObservationField.getText().toString();
                pointsList.add(new Point("Serial", Observation, false, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                        5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Observation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        Button buttonApagar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tou a carregar no botao apagar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Edit:

As tyczj pointed you can rename

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view)
```

to

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
```

and change `View view` to `final View view`. But there is no need to initialize `EditText` everytime on `Button` click

Comment: that's right, damn what a dumb I was, thank you! will be back in 10 to accept!

Answer (score 5):

because `view` is your button in that case. rename the view in your onClickListener to something else and it should work

Comment: `View view` should be final in that case

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private EditText SerialField;
    private EditText ObservationField;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.point_creation, container, false);

        SerialField = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.Serial);
        ObservationField = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.Observation);
        Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
        buttonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "tou a carregar no botao guardar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
                String Observation = ObservationField.getText().toString();
                pointsList.add(new Point("Serial", Observation, false, 1, 2, 3,
                        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        Observation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        Button buttonApagar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "tou a carregar no botao apagar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think abut what happens right here:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.point_creation, container, false);

        Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
        buttonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {  //Hello view
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "tou a carregar no botao guardar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                final EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
```

You are trying to find that View from the view that is clicked, because the clicked view is being passed to the `onClick` method.

Solution:

Try to initialize your EditText in the onCreateView not in the onClick and make it Global like this:

```
 EditText SerialField, ObservationField;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.point_creation, container, false);
        SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
        ObservationField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Observation);

        Button buttonGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move these two lines out of the `setOnClickListener`

```
final EditText SerialField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Serial);
final EditText ObservationField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Observation);
```

It will work..

Have a try...

Comment: Accept the answer if it was usefull @user2421208

Comment: will do as soon as I can and if it's possible. Raghunandan answered first :/

Comment: I pointed out the correct solution naa..and i'm a beginner so please support me..